# Hiding/showing multiple div elements according to the data fetch from the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my PHP code which fetches the multiple row results from the database.

```
<p id = "show-desc">
<?php  echo $db_description = $row['description']; ?>  </p>
```

And here is my jQuery code which initially hides the paragraph after fetching the result from database and on pressing the button it shows the hidden paragraph.

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#show-desc").hide();
     $("#show-details").click(function(){
         $("#show-desc").show();
});
});
</script>
```

Now, it works fine where there is only one row fetch from the database.
But it not working when there are multiple rows. It only hides the first row and rest of them are visible.

Comment: haven't you tried implementing classes instead of ids?

Comment: Does paragraph id repeats too?? or only the content of para increase?

Comment: "Here is my PHP code which fetches the multiple row results from the database."...the PHP you've shown will only print one field. Please show it in context. If you are using a loop to repeat this output in PHP then you have an issue because it will create many HTML elements with the same ID - this is not valid, the browser cannot tell them apart, so it cannot know which one to show and hide

Comment: It sounds like you're duplicating `id` attributes, which is invalid HTML. Use classes instead, and traverse the DOM to find elements related to the one which raised the event. If you want an example of this, please edit your question to include a more complete sample of the HTML

Comment: Use class instead of id for `<p>` tags

Comment: yeah, I've tried class also . but it is showing multiple buttons not the content in it. Nothing happens when I press the button.

Comment: " it is showing multiple buttons not the content in it"...I've no idea what you did to make that happen, but I don't think it's what people here were suggesting. Please show the HTML in context properly as requested, and also show how you create your "show-details" button as well. I assume there will end up being one button per paragraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
<p class="show-desc"> </p> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".show-desc").hide();
     $(".show-details").click(function(){
          $(this).show(); //
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is `$(".show-details")` in this code? We don't know from the OP's code, but it certainly isn't the same element as the hidden paragraph. It's likely it's a button. Therefore your code will simply make the button visible...but if the user clicked it, the button is already visible...and anyway that's not what is needed. As per my last comment on the main question, we don't have enough info to solve the problem in full.